# Apply function to dataframe based on unique values

Tags: r, function, unique, lapply, rbind

I need to apply a function to a dataframe, subsetted or grouped by unique values.

My data looks like this:

```
FID FIX_NO ELK_ID ALTITUDE     XLOC    YLOC DATE_TIME JulDate
1   NA   5296    393 2260.785 547561.3 4771900        NA     140
2   NA   5297    393 2254.992 547555.9 4771906        NA     140
3   NA   5298    393 2256.078 547563.5 4771901        NA     140
4   NA   5299    393 2247.047 547564.7 4771907        NA     140
5   NA   5300    393 2264.875 547558.3 4771903        NA     140
6   NA   5301    393 2259.496 547554.1 4771925        NA     140
...
24247   NA   4389    527 2204.047 558465.7 4775358        NA     161
24248   NA   4390    527 2279.078 558884.1 4775713        NA     161
24249   NA   4391    527 2270.590 558807.9 4775825        NA     161
24250   NA   4392    527 2265.258 558732.2 4775805        NA     161
24251   NA   4393    527 2238.375 558672.4 4775781        NA     161
24252   NA   4394    527 2250.055 558686.6 4775775        NA     161
```

My goal is to make a new data.frame by randomly selecting 4 rows per each JulDate for each unique ELK_ID.
If I do it by hand, for each unique ELK_ID my code is as follows:

`oneelk <- subset(dataset, ELK_ID == 393)`
`newdata <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(oneelk,oneelk$JulDate),
                             function(x)x[sample(1:nrow(x),4),]))`

There are **>40 ELK_IDs**, so I need to automate the process. **Please help!**

Comment: Use the `{}` button to put data in code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset)[,.SD[sample(.N,4)],by=list(ELK_ID,JulDate)]

#    ELK_ID JulDate FID FIX_NO ALTITUDE     XLOC    YLOC DATE_TIME
# 1:    393     140  NA   5297 2254.992 547555.9 4771906        NA
# 2:    393     140  NA   5299 2247.047 547564.7 4771907        NA
# 3:    393     140  NA   5298 2256.078 547563.5 4771901        NA
# 4:    393     140  NA   5300 2264.875 547558.3 4771903        NA
# 5:    527     161  NA   4394 2250.055 558686.6 4775775        NA
# 6:    527     161  NA   4392 2265.258 558732.2 4775805        NA
# 7:    527     161  NA   4390 2279.078 558884.1 4775713        NA
# 8:    527     161  NA   4393 2238.375 558672.4 4775781        NA
```

NB, this will only work if there are at least 4 rows for every combination of `ELK_ID` and `JulDate`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, unfortunately it looks like I do have some ELK_IDs with less than 4 JulDates.

Comment: Then use `sample(.N,min(.N,4))` instead of `sample(.N,4)`. This will take a random sample of however many rows there are, up to 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create an index using `tapply` and then just subset (assuming your data set called `df`)

```
indx <- unlist(tapply(seq_len(dim(df)[1L]), 
                      df[, c("JulDate", "ELK_ID")], 
                      function(x) sample(x, 4)))
df[indx, ]
```

Comment: when I define indx, I get an error that the 'arguments must be the same length'. I know that for each value of ELK_ID there is a corresponding value for JulDate, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Comment: The reason you are getting this error is because you converted your data set to `data.table` object (you've ran @jihoward code first). If you want this to work, run this on your original data set

Answer (score 1):

Try to split using both columns, maybe `split(dataset, dataset[, c("ELK_ID", "JulDate")])`

Answer (score 0):

Might as well add a `dplyr` solution too:

```
library(dplyr)
newdf <- yourdata %>%
          group_by(ELK_ID, JulDate) %>%
          sample_n(4)
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want, but I need admin approval to update my R version so I can access dplyr. Will let you know how it goes! Thanks!

Comment: The library(data.table) solution worked without having to update my version of R. Thanks for the help though!